# Replication Snapshot login failure

Tags: sql-server, replication, snapshot

I am attempting to run a snapshot for replication using the following settings.

> -Publisher [CUST-5NSA] -PublisherDB [Ticketing] -Distributor [CUST-5NSA] -Publication [TicketingBase] -ReplicationType 2
>   -DistributorSecurityMode 1

When this runs I get the following error:

> Connecting to Distributor CUST-5NSA The replication agent had
>   encountered an exception Source: Replication Exception Type:
>   Microsoft.SQLServer.Replication.ConnectionFailureException Exception
>   Message: Login failed for user 'CUST-5NSA\Administrator' Message Code:
>   18456

The strange thing is that the event viewer shows that the error is actually that the administrator account doesn't exist which is impossible since I can log in with it.

But even more important there is no setting that I can find that uses the administrator account for replication.  We have another account that we use for all the replication settings.

Can anyone point to where this login is coming from?

Comment: When you say that you can log in with that account, *where* can you log in with it? It looks like your distributor and publisher are on the same server, but does that account have the appropriate permissions in both your Ticketing database and the distribution database? According to BOL, the account needs db_owner in both. Sysadmin would also work.

Comment: I can log into windows with it.  

I checked the access and made sure it had db_owner in both and I'm still getting the same error.

It would be interesting to know where it is getting the log in information to use because as far as I can tell the Administrator account isn't defined in any of the replication settings I can find.

Comment: It's getting that information from the account that's running the SQL agent jib. If there's no proxy set up, it's the service account for the dwell agent. Are there failed login attempts logged in your error log?

Comment: So even running snapshot.exe manually uses the sql agent service?  I've been running it manually to attempt to get more information about the error.  

I'll check that out.

Comment: Nope; I assumed that you were running it through a SQL Agent job. It will use the credentials of the account that is running it. If that's you running it from the command line, then it'll use your account.

Answer (score 3):

Go to `Replication/Local Publications`. Right click on your publication and select `Properties`. In the `Publication Properties` dialog, from the left panel, select `Agent Security`.

Now you can check security settings of `Snapshot Agent` ( and also Log Reader Agent ) by clicking on the associated `Security Settings` button. After clicking that button, you see a dialog that by selecting '`Using the following SQL Server login`', you can provide the credentials of a SQL Server account on the Publisher that has enough permissions to access the Publisher database or just select '`By impersonating the process account`' to use `Windows Authentication`.